# android: How to replace a word with another text in edittext using addTextChangedListener?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `edittext`. I want when the use type a sentence. After a space some words will be changed into another. I want to perform this using `addTextChangedListener` only.
I'm using the following code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: you are already doing this if you add the code in these methods :)

Comment: What have you tried and what are the problems you are encountering ? After all, with the code you have above, you're only missing 1 single line of basic java String operation...

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable str) {
                Editable ab = new SpannableStringBuilder(str.toString().replace("A", "a"));
                editText.setText(ab);
            }


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like this. first check if user entered space. then split the word from spaces and replace your words.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                if(s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).length()==0)
                {
                   replaceWord(s.toString());
                }

                }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });



private void replaceWord(String word)
{
   String wordsList[] = word.split(" ");
   //Replace words here
}
```

Comment: This is my code replacement methos , but it is not working.......... private void replaceWord(String word) {
  String wordsList[] = word.split(" ");

  for (String string : wordsList) {
   if (word.equals("xyz")) {
    string.replaceAll("xyz", "abc");
   }
   if (word.equals("lmn")) {
    string.replaceAll("lmn", "def");
   }
  }
 }